# Updating the value of a column based on another column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, search

I have a dataframe as df:
[image]

Now based on a string processing function on the 1st column ['Message'], test(l1,l2) i get a dict like rect_d{}:

```
{'ISIN': ':',
 'ISIN :': 'KE5000008986',
 'SETTLEMENT DATE': '-',
 'SETTLEMENT DATE -': '06/01/2020',
 'TRADE DATE': '-'}
```

Based on the value of dict, i intend to update the similar information on the same row on different columns, like based on the last value of Settlement date, i want to update SETTLEMENT DATE on the same row.

I have written my code accordingly:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    split_t=df['Message'][idx].split()
    ret_d= test(items, split_t)
    for key in ret_d:
        print(key)
        if key=='SETTLEMENT DATE' or 'SETTLEMENT DATE:' or 'Settlement date :' or 'SETTLEMENT DATE -':
            df.loc[idx,'SETTLEMENT DATE']=ret_d[key]
        elif key=='ISIN:' or 'ISIN' or 'ISIN :':
            df.loc[idx,'ISIN']=ret_d[key]
        elif key=='CASH ACCOUNT':
            df.loc[idx,'CASH ACCOUNT']=ret_d[key]
        else: print('done')
    break
```

Which should ideally populate my df with the values. But it has not just the first value is populated.
[image]

I couldn't do as the values are not that straight forward:

```
df['key']=df['rect_d'].apply(lambda x:rect_d[x])
```

Is there anything I'm missing in updating the df? Any insight is highly appreciated.

df for reference in df.to_dict() format:

```
{'CASH ACCOUNT': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'CLEARING BIC': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'CLIENT NAME': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'ISIN': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'MARKET': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'Message': {0: '{1:F01SCBLMUMUBSSU0422020871}{2:O5990735200109UBSWUS33BSCI12525443762001091635N}{3:{108:AMDBHDVHU7RUGRHA}}{4:\n:20:WICTIN010Q55PK19\n:79:ACCOUNT/2EVERECFNG\nSENDER/WICTIN01/Ravali Nandi\nRECEIVER/SCB Mauritius\nHI TEAM,\n.\nCAN YOU PLEASE PROCESS BELOW\nTRADE AS RECEIVE FREE OF PAYMENT\nAS PER BELOW DETAILS\n.\nTRADE DETAILS\nSAFE ACC NO : 045891400139\nQUANTITY : 2,840,100\nISIN : KE5000008986\nPSET - XNAIKEN1\nDEAG - SCBLKENX\n70E - SHARE RECEIVED FROM RWANDA TO KENYA\nTRADE DATE - 06/01/2020\nSETTLEMENT DATE - 06/01/2020\nRegards\nRavali\n-}{5:{CHK:97709F6E1473}}',
  1: '{1:F01SCBLMUMUXSSU0092740678}{2:O5991259200113SCBLKENXXSSU00927406782001131359N}{4:\n:20:CANC\n:79:KE0022282/MK1\n.\nKINDLY CANCEL\nMT543\nREF KE0022282/MK1\n.\nKIND\nREGARDS,\nSCB SECURITIES SERVICES\nKENYA\n-}',
  2: '{1:F01SCBLMUMUXXXX0092826091}{2:O5992027200114SCBLHKHHXXXX00928260912001141627N}{3:{108:UIGMU18026A00799}}{4:\n:20:LEKO14012020RVP\n:21:UIGMU18026A00799\n:79:Safekeep Account : 3CEXOCUSCL                    \nPlease accept the below trade instruction TYPE RVP\nPORTFOLIO ACCOUNT - 045887500023 ISIN KYG5462G107\n3 SECURITY NAME - LEKOIL LTD TRADE DATE 14 JANUARY\n2020 SETTLEMENT DATE 16 JANUARY 2020 QUANTITY - 1\nSETTLEMENT AMOUNT - 7.73 GBP COUNTERPARTY BIC PAR\nBGB2L CREST CODE - FFQAQ SELLER BIC - CVGXUS33 STA\nMP DUTY - GBOX PSET - CRSTGB22\n-}',
  3: '{1:F01SCBLMUMUXXXX0088474512}{2:O5992028200114SCBLHKHHXXXX00884745122001141628N}{3:{108:UIGMU18026A00800}}{4:\n:20:LEKO14012020DVP\n:21:UIGMU18026A00800\n:79:Safekeep Account : 3CEXOCUSCL                    \nPlease accept the below trade instruction TYPE DVP\nPORTFOLIO ACCOUNT - 045887500023 ISIN KYG5462G107\n3 SECURITY NAME - LEKOIL LTD TRADE DATE 14 JANUARY\n2020 SETTLEMENT DATE 16 JANUARY 2020 QUANTITY - 1\nSETTLEMENT AMOUNT - 7.66 GBP COUNTERPARTY BIC PAR\nBGB2L CREST CODE - FFQAQ SELLER BIC - CVGXUS33 STA\nMP DUTY - GBOX PSET - CRSTGB22\n-}'},
 'New Context': {0: 'SSTM', 1: 'SSTM', 2: 'SSTM', 3: 'SSTM'},
 'PRICE CFA': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'SAFEKEEP ACCOUNT': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'SCA': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'SECURITY NAME': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'SETTLEMENT DATE': {0: '-', 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'TRADE DATE': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None},
 'TRADE TYPE': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None}}
```

items:

```
items=['SETTLEMENT DATE', 'SETTLEMENT DATE:','Settlement date :','SETTLEMENT DATE -', 'CASH ACCOUNT', 'CASH ACCOUNT:',
       'ISIN:',  'ISIN', 'ISIN :',
       'TRADE DATE','TRADE DATE:']
```

Comment: Could you please post your DataFrame values in form of text so that we can create/test it on our systems, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 updated with the same.

Comment: @Strayhorn What is `items`?

Answer (score 2):

#### [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

We can create records by iterating over the strings in message column and mapping each string to the `dictionary` using the `test` function, then we can create a new dataframe from these records and update the value in the original dataframe from this newly created dataframe

```
df.update(pd.DataFrame([test(items, msg.split()) for msg in df['Message']], index=df.index))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i don't think this way the values are populated properly in the newly created df. I think conditional checking are missing which is populating only '-' on three columns and nothing on others.

Comment: @Strayhorn Please check the edit, and I think should work as long as your function `test` will return the dictionaries in proper format containing all the keys (`column names`) that needs to be updated.